# Windows Git - set up SSH key

Tags: git

I have created a public key and private key on my Windows 7 box to my Git server and I can use it successfully when I uses Tortoise Git in windows.

I now want to use it purely on the command line and cannot get it to work because msysGit is not pickup up my ssh keys.

Can someone help me with instructions on how to help mysysGit pick up the keys which I have stored in ...

```
c:\.ssh.
   rsa-key-20160411-priv.ppk
   rsa-key-20160411-pub
   id_rsa
```

I saw a post on the net suggesting putting it at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh
```

might help but that has not.

thanks

Comment: what is your $HOME path? is it pointing to same location where .ssh is stored ? check link for help http://kylecordes.com/2008/git-windows-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-cmd.bat` (packaged with [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)) set by default the environment variable `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`.

In your case, you need to set it to `C:\` in order for git to look for ssh keys in `%HOME\.ssh`.